# Jest Issue: Could not locate module ./images/ticketsMessageIcon.png mapped as: RelativeImageStub

Tags: react-native, jestjs

Getting this error after upgrading to `RN 62.2`

```
Configuration error:

    Could not locate module ./images/ticketsMessageIcon.png mapped as:
    RelativeImageStub.

    Please check your configuration for these entries:
    {
      "moduleNameMapper": {
        "/^[@.\/a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+\.(png|gif)$/": "RelativeImageStub"
      },
      "resolver": null
    }
```

The moduleNameMapper didn't change and here is what it looks like

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
      "^image![a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+$": "GlobalImageStub",
      "^[@./a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+\\.(png|gif)$": "RelativeImageStub",
      "^globalize$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/globalize/dist/node-main.js"
    },
```